# Scrollview with an ad on top that doesn't scroll

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview, admob

I'm getting an error saying that Scrollview can only host one child. What I'm trying to do is make it so that the entire interface scrolls minus the ad at the top. So as it stands now I've got the ad showing up in a linear layout, with the scrollview inside that. Inside the scrollview is another linear layout and everything else is inside that one. I'm at a loss as to what to do. I really need the ad to not scroll but if I have to put the ad code inside the scrollview I will. I'm just pretty certain there's a way to do what I want though I can't find it.

Here's my xml layout...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/AdLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Ad Placeholder -->

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a15138b1a7adad2"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/BaseScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/baseVerticalLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/Sad" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Happy" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/happinessBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/Tired" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Awake" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/energyBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/Calm" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Anxious" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/anxietyBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/No_Pain" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Max_Pain" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/painBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/noteTextFieldID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/Note_Hint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="@integer/NoteLimit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enterButtonID"
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="dialogPop"
            android:text="@string/EnterButtonText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It looks like this ScrollView only has one child... Trying saving this file again and cleaning the project.

Comment: I'll try that. I can't figure out why it's not liking the scrollview but I'll give cleaning it a shot. (Though if I remember correctly I did clean the project a few times yesterday while I was working on this.)

Comment: with the layout as it is right now (in your post) what is the behavior that you get on the screen? is there an error? or just malfunction?

Comment: In my logcat I'm seeing that it's giving me an exception and saying that scrollview can only host one child even though it's displaying the screen properly. Also for some reason my program isn't linked to my UI anymore like it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified version of the example ScrollView layout from AdMob's [Ad Catalog](https://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/adcatalog/res/layout/scrollviewexample.xml?repo=ad-catalog-android) project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/adView">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/advancedLayouts_scroll_view_lorem_ipsum"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You don't want the ad to be on top of your `ScrollView`, so you want to explicitly tell it to sit below the `com.google.ads.AdView`.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get the UI to work fine aside from the fact that now it wants to overlay the ad over my application instead of moving the UI down to accommodate. Any idea how I need to make that happen?

Comment: Did you add this line onto your ScrollView, or sibling element of the AdView: `android:layout_below="@id/adView"`? That should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me perfectly , please tell me if any more help is needed .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx" />

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back3" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Text" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="Text2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How is this different from what I have aside from having the relativelayout layer in between the outer Linearlayout and the scrollview?